An inequality relates to edge chromatic-polynomial
Properly colored graph (edge has color) means that any two adjacent edges have distinct colors.
The edge chromatic polynomial $ech(G, k)$ gives the number of proper edge coloring of the $G$ with $k$ colors. Then what is the lower bound of  $ech(G, k)$ for a graph $G$ with $m$ edges?
For the above problem, we have the following result:
Thm. For any $m$ and and graph $G$ with $m$ edges and edge chromatic number $\chi'$, if $k \ge \frac{6}{7}m \ge \chi'$, then
$$
ech(G, k) \ge \frac{k^m}{e^{m+2}}.
$$
Now we consider the following problem:
For an integer $s\le m$, if we fix $s$ edges's colors in $G$ with $m$ edges, then  define $ech(G_s,k)$ as the number of $k$-colorings of the subgraph of $G$ with remain edges such that $G$ is properly colored. Then do we have
$$
\frac{ech(G,k)}{ech(G_s,k)} \ge (ck)^s?
$$
for some constant $c$.
Or is it right as $m \rightarrow \infty$?
Remark: we only consider the case that $ech(G_s,k)> 0$ and $G$ has no multi-edge. We may need $k \ge \frac{6}{7}m$ or others.
Or are there any research results on $ech(G_s,k)$?
A similar result is here.
A similar question is here.

Consider the star $K_{1,m}$.  It has no proper edge colourings with less than $m$ colours, but your first formula says that it does.  Am I misreading?

Thanks, l loss something and i have added the edge chromatic number condition in thm.
